# Проблема с редактированием сообщений aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Хочу отредактировать сообщение отправленное с помощью aiogram у пользователя, сам бот отправляет человеку сообщение с фотографией, спустя несколько секунд я хочу, чтобы эта фотография менялась на видео, к примеру - `https://media.giphy.com/media/13HBDT4QSTpveU/giphy.gif`

Код отправки сообщения пользователю:

```
async def search_start(message):
    await bot.delete_message(chat_id=message.from_user.id, message_id=message.message_id)

    query = message.text.capitalize()

    message_text = f"""` TEST '{query}'.`"""

    message = await message.answer_photo(
        photo='https://qps.ru/13bwp',
        caption=message_text,
        parse_mode='MarkdownV2'
    )

    return message
```

Код с помощью которого я хочу отредактировать ранее отправленное сообщение заменив фото на видео:

```
async def del_message(message):
    await bot.edit_message_media(
        message.chat.id,
        message.message_id,
        video='https://media.giphy.com/media/13HBDT4QSTpveU/giphy.gif'
    )
```

Хочу обратить ваше внимание, что переменная message успешно попадает в функцию `del_message()`, я просто не знаю как можно изменить фото на видео.
И если запустить этот код, произойдет ошибка:

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-17' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at C:\Users\Maxim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:409> exception=TypeError("edit_message_media() got an unexpected keyword argument 'video'")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Maxim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 417, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
  File "C:\Users\Maxim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 238, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "C:\Users\Maxim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\Maxim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 259, in process_update
    return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
  File "C:\Users\Maxim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "c:\Users\Maxim\Desktop\globaltimezonesbot\globaltimezonesbot\globaltimezonesbot.py", line 57, in message_answer
    await query_checker(x, query)
  File "c:\Users\Maxim\Desktop\globaltimezonesbot\globaltimezonesbot\globaltimezonesbot.py", line 111, in query_checker
    await search_error(x, query)
  File "c:\Users\Maxim\Desktop\globaltimezonesbot\globaltimezonesbot\globaltimezonesbot.py", line 99, in search_error
    await asyncio.create_task(del_message(x))
  File "c:\Users\Maxim\Desktop\globaltimezonesbot\globaltimezonesbot\globaltimezonesbot.py", line 61, in del_message
    await bot.edit_message_media(
TypeError: edit_message_media() got an unexpected keyword argument 'video'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для того, что изменить медиа-файлы в сообщении, Вам нужно создать один из [InputMedia](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inputmedia) объектов, и передать объект в функцию `edit_message_media`:

```py
async def del_message(message):
    media = InputMediaAnimation(media='https://media.giphy.com/media/ZdT2zDh3Bvnkk/giphy.gif')
    await bot.edit_message_media(
        media=media,
        chat_id=message.chat.id,
        message_id=message.message_id
    )
```